# get the details of child checkbox while clicking on the parent checboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of checkboxes with select all and deselect all options... Is it possible to get the details( id, class, name) of the child checkboxes associated each main checkbox while clicking on select all option..

http://jsfiddle.net/nBh4L/2/

```
$(function(){
$('.selectAll').on('click', function(evt){
var group = $(this).attr('data-group'),
    isChecked = !!($(this).prop('checked'));
$('input[value="' + group + '"]').prop('checked', isChecked);    
})

$('.entity').on('click', function(evt){
var group = $(this).attr('value'),
    siblings = $('input[value="' + group + '"]'),
    isChecked = true;
siblings.each(function(idx, el){
  if(!$(el).prop('checked')) {
    isChecked = false;
    return;
  }
})

$('.selectAll[data-group="' + group + '"]').prop('checked', isChecked);

})
})​
```

Comment: in jsfiddle??its wrking fine... use jquery

Comment: Why would you make another question when you made one on a similar problem just 4 hours ago?

Comment: coz ive marked it correct.. and it ends there.. right?

Comment: @SamDaSilva Learn to edit your old question. Better for the site and for you. There are already alot of answers in that question that have tried your problem, so you would get help faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
SEE DEMO: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp87

```
$('.selectAll').on('click', function(evt){
    var group = $(this).attr('data-group'),
        isChecked = !!($(this).prop('checked'));
    $('input[value="' + group + '"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
    siblings = $('input[value="' + group + '"]');
      siblings.each(function(){
          alert($(this).attr('name'));
      })     
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("input.select").on("click", function() {
        var $entities = $(this).siblings().find("input.entity");
        $entities.prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));

        //      This would also work if you want an array with ids.
        //      console.log($entities.map(function() {
        //          return $(this).attr("id");
        //      }));

        $entities.each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    });

    $("input.entity").on("click", function() {
        var $entityGroup = $(this).siblings().andSelf();
        $(this).parent().siblings("input.select").prop("checked", $entityGroup.length === $entityGroup.filter(":checked").length);
    });
});
```

This is just an small add to the answer I gave to your other question a couple of hours ago.

```
        $entities.each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        });
```

The above logs the ids of the different entities to the console. Hopefully you understand how you could use and get the attributes from this example.

This is also an option, if you want it all in an array:

```
        console.log($entities.map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("id");
        }));
```

## [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/EBxSu/9/)